# Elegant check of equalities in a 3Blue1Brown post on the Leibniz formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, generating-functions

At [this point on the presentation](https://youtu.be/NaL_Cb42WyY?t=79) the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80):

$$1- \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5 - \frac 1 7+\cdots= \frac \pi 4$$

is expressed with "a few lines of calculus" as

$$\begin{align}
1- \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5 - \frac 1 7+\cdots & =\int_0^1 \left(1 - x^2 + x^4 - \cdots \right) dx \tag 1\\[2ex]
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \tag 2\\[2ex]
&=\tan^{-1}(1) \tag 3\\[2ex]
&=\frac \pi 4
\end{align}$$

For $(1)$ my reasoning would be to just notice that integration is linear, so we end up with an infinite sum of integrals as in

$$\begin{align}
1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n} \int_0^1 x^{2n} dx &= \left. \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \right|_{x=1}\\[2ex] 
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac \pi 4
\end{align}$$

$(2)$ can be expanded to $(1)$ with polynomial long division, or recognizing it as the generating function or the Taylor series of the integrand in $(1).$

Finally, $(3)$ is just integration.

> My question is whether there is a more "elegant" way of justifying equalities $(1)$ and $(2).$

Comment: The way you've justified points (1) and (2) seem fine on their own. For going from (1) to (2), the simplest way to see that in my opinion is to know that $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+ \dots$ (which is a basic geometric series), and so $\frac{1}{1+ x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - \dots$.

Comment: @Quotable Totally! Much more elegant! Thank you!

Comment: "Integration is linear" technically only applies to finite sums. This infinite series is conditionally convergent, so we do need to be careful.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729249/72031 for justification of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Quotable, one way to think of this is infinite Geometric Progression, with the first term as $1$ and the common ratio as $-x^2$.

Another way could be the binomial expansion of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$.

$$(1+x)^{n}=1+nx +\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2!}x^2 +\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3 \cdots$$
Substitute $x^2$ in place of $x$ and $-1$ in place of $n$.

Comment: This does not justify $(1)$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Uhhh, it does.

Comment: I have to agree with @mr_e_man. The justification of $(1)$ is not that simple. Either you deal with this specific series or apply general theorems on power series and uniform convergence. It is simpler however to deal with this series directly.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh I haven't learnt anything substantial about convergence (I am your average JEE student). But OP wanted to know how we we went from $1-x^2+x^4\cdots$ to $1/1+x^2$. And my method involves showing that $1/1+x^2$ is indeed $1-x^2+x^4\cdots$. I mean, LHS=RHS right?

Comment: Well, that sum of GP explains transition from (1) to (2). The first equality sign itself needs another explanation. I have given an approach via link in comments to the question which you may understand.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Okay. But could you are also tell me *why* my method os wrong? I haven't understood that yet.

Comment: Your method is not wrong. It only explains the second equality between $1-x^2+x^4-\dots$ and $1/(1+x^2)$. It does not explain the first equality ie how $1-(1/3)+(1/5)-\dots$ becomes an integral.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Oh, I see now. I thought OP simply wanted a simple explanation for $1/1+x^2=1-x^2+x^4\cdots$. And for mr_e_man's comment, I thought he meant that the two sides of the equality in question are not equal. About the "conversion" into an integral, I have no idea. But I'll think about it. Thanks for pointing it out.